# NAS Download is slower than Upload

Tags: download, nas, speed, upload, transfer

Is it normal that when i transfer a file from my pc to my Seagate Central (NAS) i have a transfer speed of 11mBps (which is normal according i have a 100mbps network card), but when i transfer a file from my Seagate Central to my PC i get a transfer speed of approximately 1mBps (with the same file)?

If not, how can i make it so i can download from my NAS at the same speed I upload to it?

Comment: Are you actually downloading it straight from the NAS, or are you downloading it through the Seagate Central cloud service? Are you using Windows Explorer or the Seagate Central web portal?

Comment: I am downloading it directly from the NAS with Windows Explorer.

Comment: Are both machines are connected to your router/switch using a LAN cable? Does your PC have a wireless adapter, and is it enabled if it does?  is the download speed consistently slow?

Comment: I do not think i would be able to reach upload speeds to my NAS of 11mBps without a LAN cable. But to answer your question, yes, i am using a LAN cable on my PC and my NAS and they are connected to 2 different switches that are connected to my router (Linksys EA6200).